# EF Core (Oracle) ambiguous column

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following classes (inheritance):

```cs
public class Animal
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I know that the property `name` should be in `Animal`. It's just for this example

Now when I select all entities:

```cs
_context.Animals.ToListAsync();
```

I get the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    "m0"."ID",
    "m0"."NAME",
    "m1"."NAME",
    CASE
        WHEN "m1"."ID" IS NOT NULL THEN N'Dog'
        WHEN "m0"."ID" IS NOT NULL THEN N'Cat' 
    END "Discriminator"
FROM ANIMAL
LEFT JOIN DOG "m0" ON "m0".ID = ANIMAL.ID
LEFT JOIN CAT "m1" ON "m1".ID = ANIMAL.ID
```

The generated SQL leads to an Oracle exception

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

(because of the `name` column).

Is there any workaround or fix for this?

Using `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore@6.21.61`

Comment: Could you please try to change the `column name` other than only `name` as you have used `name` both in `Base` and `derived` which cannot work in case of `database entity` to `POCO class`, Therefore, use `AS for naming Alias` So please rename and let us know the update.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Of course, putting the name prop into Animal (base) or renaming the columns to be unique would work, but thats not the point. Maybe the example is a little bit confusing. I want to select classes where subclasses have the same property(names).  I expected that EF-Core sets aliases to the props but it doesn't or can I force that by setting additonal expressions?

Comment: No, entityframework cannot do that, and it doesn't work this way for sure. You either need to rename them or need to send name with proper alias using `TSQL` mechanisam.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron thank you for your response. I feared that. Could you please give an example how I send the name with proper alias using ```TSQL```?

Comment: Sure I will do that, I will provide an example using `TSQL view`  will that works for you?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron , EF can deal with this kind of scenarios. Check my answer below.

Comment: Let's wait for `OPs` reply, if that works then you are done. Thanks for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with EF Core 6 and EF is able to deal with this:

The context:

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Dog> Dogs { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; } = default!;
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseOracle("my random connextion string");
    }
}

public abstract class Animal
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
   public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

The query:

```cs
var a = db.Animals.ToQueryString();
```

The result:

```sql
SELECT a.Id, a.Discriminator, a.Name, a.Dog_Name FROM Animals a
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code. Unfortunately the difference is, that in your code EF-Core defines the column names ("Dog_Name"). In our case the column-names are already predefined, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, in my code, migration creates two columns: `Name` and `Dog_Name` in the same table, this is default behavior. But EF is [ready to share the column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#shared-columns)

Comment: @SNO did you try with shared columns as i explained on previous comment?

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: Did you try to move `Name`to sueprclass `Animal`? did you try with shared column as I mentioned?